# conver to ajax to curl -> curl localhost:8080/oauth/token -h foo:bar -d grant_type=password -d username=test@gmail.com -d password=1

Tags: ajax, curl, oauth, token

I want conver to ajax to curl.

curl localhost:8080/oauth/token -h foo:bar -d grant_type=password -d username=test@gmail.com -d password=1

The above command succeeds.

but ajax fail...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic' + btoa('foo:bar'));

    },
    data: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: '1'
    }, 
    complete: function(result) {
        console.log('complete', result);
    },

    success: function(result) {
        console.log('success', result);
    },

    error: function(result) {
        console.log('error', result);
    }
});
```

I converted to ajax and the following error appears.

Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

responseJSON : undefined

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Modify OauthServer

Change "source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configAutenticacao);" to "source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/token", configAutenticacao);" in corsFilterRegistrationBean